# How to upload image to amazon s3 in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, ckeditor, gjs

I am trying to upload an image to an amazon s3 bucket using ck-editor and used 'gjs-plugin-s3, I am using the right credentials but still it's saying "403 Forbidden error".

I am fed up from this, can anyone assist me to resolve this issue?

For this I am using the things below:

```
'gjs-plugin-s3': {
            imgFormats: ["png", "jpeg", "jpg"],
            bucketName: "bodylesscms",
            prefix: "content/img/",
            accessKeyId: 'XYZ',
            secretAccessKey: 'XYZ',

}
```

Am I using these parameter correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be providing accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken (temporary credentials) to this plugin. We should not use accessKeys directly in code. Check this if you still have any doubts in implementing (https://github.com/chaitanya11/grapesjs-plugin-s3/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: And you have to use your own bucket names, here "bodylesscms" bucket is already existing bucket in others account. So, your credentials will not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

It works actually, I was using invalid Key Id.

Thanks guys for your attention.